# VS code Jupyter output not showing full output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I wrote an extended input code where user will input many options. So the output generated will continuously build up.

However, juypter notebook in VS code will limit the output to this:
[image]

there will be '...' after serveral input prompts so i cant see what i have input and what the next prompt is.

I tried to use this

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the number of lines that are displayed in the output via the settings. Change it to something higher, eg. 500:

```
"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 500
```

Open VS Code > File > Preferences > Settings. Then in the settings page look for "notebook". Scroll down to the "Notebook > Output: Text Line Limit", which by default should have 50 as value.
I hope this helps.

Comment: yeap it helps. Another question, the buffering is quite slow. There are some instances in which the input prompt is shown but not the text. Hence essentially I'm blind picking my option without the menu printed. This problem doesn't happen in IDLE.